# How to select the only panel of the effect plot I want using the "effects" package in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, data-visualization

I'm using Fox et al's effects package in R to visualize the predicted probabilities of my logit result.

This is the data
[Link to data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwqwPEm02yTseEVueDB3VFVXZDQ/view?usp=sharing)

And his is what I've done:

```
logit1 <- glm(vote00 ~ age+ I(age^2) + hsdeg + coldeg, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=data)
```

And my plot looks like the following with:

```
plot(Effect(focal.predictors = c("hsdeg","coldeg", "age"), 
        mod=logit1, 
        xlevels=list(age=seq(20,90,1), hsdeg=c(0,1), coldeg=c(0,1))),
        type = "response", 
        ylab="probability of voting", 
        main="Predicted Probabilities of Age and Education")
```

[Plot to be modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNUwR.png)

However, I'd like to remove the first and the third panel of the effect display, as the second and the fourth panel are the relevant ones. And suggestion as how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to hack into the generated effect object and modify the levels for the variables.

```
eff <- Effect(focal.predictors = c("hsdeg","coldeg", "age"), 
              mod=logit1, 
              xlevels=list(age=seq(20,90,1), hsdeg=c(0,1), coldeg=c(0,1)))
eff$variables$hsdeg$is.factor <- TRUE
eff$variables$hsdeg$levels <- c(1)
plot(eff, 
     type = "response", 
     ylab="probability of voting", 
     main="Predicted Probabilities of Age and Education")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the plot couldn't seem to be modified. I'm guessing it's because I'm plotting Pr(vote) against age with two education (high school and college) dummies. I'm still trying to figure out a way to remove the panel of (hsdeg=0; coldeg=1) and (hsdeg=0; coldeg=0). Any further suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you can share your model or the underlying data? That way we can reproduce using your example and not sample data. If you're willing to share your model the easiest way is to run `dput(logit1)` in your R console and paste it as part of your question.

Comment: I just edited my original answer to include link to the data. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for attaching the data. There is only one small change you need to make and I've updated my answer accordingly. It's that you need to also update the variable to force it as a factor like this:  `eff$variables$hsdeg$is.factor <- TRUE`

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help and Welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer or any other response solved your issue, please upvote and mark as accepted.